# When i add data to SQLite DataBase,i want to update the RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-recyclerview

For example,RecyclerView is in "A" Activity,then  intent to "B" Activity.Later,when I add data to SQLiteDataBase in "B" Activity,i carry the `finish()` to go back "A" Activity. I want to update the RecyclerView.I did this  like the following,but don't work:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("TAG", "resume");
    allCaseItemList = getPersonalCaseinfo();
    mListViewAllCaseItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

see here:
`allCaseItemList`is my datalist,`mListViewAllCaseItemAdapter`is my customAdapter

Comment: `getPersonalCaseinfo()` is  used  to get data from SQLiteDataBase

Comment: use some Cursor adapter like https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b used with a `CursorLoader` will do that automagically

Comment: I don't want to use this adapter,so what should  i do  to solve this question

Comment: so what adapter are you using?

Comment: I user customadapter  extends  listviewadapter  of  telerik

Comment: listviewadapter in RecyclerView ???

Comment: use CursorRecyclerAdapter, you will see how your life become easier with that

Comment: no  it is in  telerik ,a open source UI framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this,

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("TAG", "resume");
    allCaseItemList.clear();
    allCaseItemList.addAll(getPersonalCaseinfo());
    mListViewAllCaseItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```